# Refreshing page/web-part on pressing the "Escape" key in C#?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html

I would like to fire a refresh event when the user presses the "Escape" key OR would prefer to fire the image click event on pressing the Esc key
What is the best way to achieve this?
Thanks

```
        $clone.click(function (e) { //action when magnified image is clicked on
        var $this = $(this)
        var imageinfo = $this.data('$relatedtarget').data('imgshell')
        jQuery.imageMagnify.refreshoffsets($(window), $this.data('$relatedtarget'), imageinfo) //refresh offset positions of original and warped images
        $this.stop().animate({ opacity: 0, left: imageinfo.attrs.x, top: imageinfo.attrs.y, width: imageinfo.attrs.w, height: imageinfo.attrs.h }, setting.duration,
        function () {
            $this.hide()
            $this.data('$relatedtarget').css({ opacity: 1 }) //reveal original image
        }) //end animate
    }) //end click



//This is what I put in, but I'd like it to not just refresh but actually perform the same         function as OnClick as above
$(document).keyup(function (e) { //action when magnified image is clicked on
 if (e.keyCode == 27) { //escape key 
     window.location.reload(); 

        }
}) //end click



 $clone.keyup(function (e) { //action when 'Esc' key is pressed after magnifying image 

        if (e.keyCode == 27) { //escape key 

        var $this = $(this)
        var imageinfo = $this.data('$relatedtarget').data('imgshell')
        jQuery.imageMagnify.refreshoffsets($(window), $this.data('$relatedtarget'), imageinfo) //refresh offset positions of original and warped images
        $this.stop().animate({ opacity: 0, left: imageinfo.attrs.x, top: imageinfo.attrs.y, width: imageinfo.attrs.w, height: imageinfo.attrs.h }, setting.duration,
        function () {
            $this.hide()
            $this.data('$relatedtarget').css({ opacity: 1 }) //reveal original image
        }) //end animate
                 }
    }) //end 



     }
    };
```

Comment: You would use Javascript to fire an ajax event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use jQuery for this. The implementation is very simple:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {    
    if (e.keyCode == 27) { //escape key

        //trigger the image click logic
        $("img").trigger("click"); 

        //reload the page if you still need to
        window.location.reload();
    }
});
```

If you're looking to trigger a postback, you should be able to use `__doPostBack` and override the `RaisePostBackEvent` method in the code-behind:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {    
    if (e.keyCode == 27) { //escape key
        __doPostBack("<%= Page.ClientID %>", "argument");
    }
});
```

And in the code-behind:

```
protected override void RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler source, string eventArgument)
{
    base.RaisePostBackEvent(source, eventArgument);
    if (source == Page)
    {

    }        
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works great. However I am trying to use the escape key to fire an event similar to that of my mouse click event in one of my sharepoint web parts. I have put up the code with my original question. Please note that this was a plugin I found online to use with my Images. Let me know how as to how I should use it to get the same result as the click event. Thanks again

Comment: @user1266515: If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to run the image click logic when the user presses the escape key. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I tried a function (updated in the Question) but had no luck.

Comment: @user1266515: Updated my answer to trigger the image click logic. You'll probably need to tweak it a little bit, but the example above should get you pretty close.

Comment: Got it working! Changed it to $clone.trigger("Click"); to work with my code. Thanks for following through.